# Segmentation fault strcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

```
typedef struct Movie{
    char hallName[50];
    char movieName[50];
}movie;
```

I have dynamically created movie array. In `processCommand` function:

```
char *hallName;
hallName = strtok(NULL," ");
```

and call `createHall` function with this arguments.

```
createHall(&halllName);
```

then in `createHall` function I create movie struct element and assign values here. I want to copy `hallName` to `Movie.hallName`. I do this strcpy but I get an segmentation fault in linux. In windows this code work correctly.

```
strcpy(Movie.hallName, *hallName);
```

How can I fix this problem ?

**EDIT:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     FILE *inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
     FILE *outputFile = fopen("output.txt","w+");
     char *line=NULL;
     movie *Movies = (movie*)malloc((hallNumber)*sizeof(movie));

     while(1) {
          line = readLine(inputFile);
          if (line == NULL)
               break;
          processCommand(line,outputFile,Movies,hallNumber);
     }
     free(Movies);
     closeFiles(inputFile,outputFile);
     return 1;
}

void processCommand(char *line) {

     char *hallName = NULL, *command = NULL;
     command = strtok(line, " ");

     if (strcmp(command, "CREATEHALL") == 0) {
          hallName = strtok(NULL, " ");
          createHall(&hallName);
     }
     ...
}

void createHall(char **hallName) {
    movie Movie;
    strcpy(Movie.hallName, *hallName); // problem in here
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have no context for the code. `hallName = strtok(NULL," ");` in isolation does nothing useful. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: So why are you suprised that running code which generated pointer warnings crashes?

Comment: you don't look the return of strtok he could be NULL. `command = strtok(line," ");` here too `hallName = strtok(NULL," ");` and why send a `int **` in createHall.

Comment: Do not use `strncpy`: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: Syntax error: `char *hallName = NULL, char *command = NULL;`

Comment: Post **complete** code. Complete code includes a `main` function and allows readers to compile and run the code. If you're running it with command line arguments, tell us what.

Comment: add   -if (hallName != NULL) control but still give segmentation fault. Actually no matter, i can send copy this.

Comment: `hallName` is NULL, so you're taking the address of the pointer to char and pass it into `createHall`, with pointer not pointing to anything, ...did you actually debug this? You need some leg up on to read up on pointers first and foremost.

Comment: @chqrlie I don't see a reference to `strncpy` in the OP's code. only `strcpy`.

Comment: how do you call processCommand ? it is important the argument you pass is not in read-only memory since strtok writes to it

Comment: `readLine()` is non standard. Does it allocate the array it returns a pointer to? If so, you should free it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you have a syntax error: `char *hallName = NULL, char *command = NULL;`.
- you do not check the return values of `strtok()`: it can be `NULL` in case of mismatch.
- you pass the address of the pointer `hallName` for no reason, just pass the value.
- you do not check for potential overflow: if the `hallName` points to a long string, `strcpy()` will cause a buffer overrun.
- you define `movie` as a typedef for `struct Movie` but also use `Movie` as the name for your local variable in `createHall()`.  This is very confusing.  Use `Movie` for both the `struct` tag and the `typedef` and lowercase `movie` for local variables.

Here is how to fix these problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Movie {
    char hallName[50];
    char movieName[50];
} Movie;

...

void createHall(char *hallName) {
    Movie movie;
    snprintf(movie.hallName, sizeof movie.hallName, "%s", hallName);
    ...
    // do something with movie
}

void processCommand(char *line) {

    char *hallName = NULL;
    char *command = NULL;

    command = strtok(line, " ");

    if (command && strcmp(command, "CREATEHALL") == 0) {
        hallName = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (hallName) {
            createHall(hallName);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `processCommand` modified the array to which it receives a pointer.  This is a bad API.  You should try and avoid such side effects.  `strtok()` is causing this side effect and it has other problems because it uses an internal state: avoid using this function.

---

You initially referred to `strncpy` in your question title, I edited that out since you do not actually use it. In fact you should never use `strncpy()`: its semantics are commonly misunderstood and very error prone.  See [this article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/) by Bruce Dawson.

Comment: are you sure that `movie.hallName` is a not a `char *` ? why not use strlen in place of sizeof ?

Comment: Where is it you're seeing `strncpy`?

Comment: @t0mm13b look at [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf). very powerfull function.

Comment: @t0mm13b: the OP initially mentioned `strncpy` in the question title.  He does not use and indeed should not.

Comment: @Stargateur: the definition of `Movie` is provided: `typedef struct Movie { char hallName[50]; char movieName[50]; } movie;`.  It is quite confusing that the OP uses the same name for the typedef and the local variable.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh I didn't see. Never mind.

Comment: should have pointed it out earlier on, rather than leaving it too late, as the context about ‘strncpy‘ was lost through you editing the question.

Comment: @chqrlie i tried this code snprintf instead of strcpy. I musnt snprintf because i have to compile -ansi. 
Program dont give segmentation fault but during call createHall function movieName dont go correctly in linux(in windows go correctly).For example movieName = "stardust" in process command before calling function but in createhall it is  " " why ?

Comment: *Ansi C* has been superseded 17 years ago!  `snprintf` is available on most if not all systems.  It is a shame to prevent newbies from using it!  Can you post the actual calling code that shows the error?